# <arguments> approach not overriding the template file

Tags: magento2, template, magento2.3, template-override

I wanted to override `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/name.phtml` template.

And created new layout xml update as:
File: `app/code/MagePsycho/CustomInvoice/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_invoice_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="column_name_downloadable">
            <!-- Unfortunately this is not working -->
            <!--<arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">MagePsycho_CustomInvoice::sales/items/column/downloadable/invoice/name.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>-->
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">MagePsycho_CustomInvoice::sales/items/column/downloadable/invoice/name.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

My Question here is, why this XML code

```
<arguments>
    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">MagePsycho_CustomInvoice::sales/items/column/downloadable/invoice/name.phtml</argument>
</arguments>
```

is not overriding the name.phtml file?
I think Magento recommends to avoid `<action method="setTemplate">` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a space in `MagePsycho_ CustomInvoice`:

```
<arguments>
    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">MagePsycho_ CustomInvoice::sales/items/column/downloadable/invoice/name.phtml</argument>
</arguments>
```

**Fix:**

```
<arguments>
    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">MagePsycho_CustomInvoice::sales/items/column/downloadable/invoice/name.phtml</argument>
</arguments>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but maybe somebody will find it useful. Setting template via arguments may not work if:

1. setTemplate is called somewhere in layouts on this block
2. setTemplate is called in the block

Despite setTemplate is old method and we should avoid using it, it's ok to use it if arguments don't work